# What's the correct way to specify an intent action in Manifest File?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest, intentfilter

The tutorial says to use `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE` in the action element within the XML `intent-filter`.

However,

> this is the value of a String constant ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE in
>   android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager

-- I am new to Android but in general programming it is encouraged to use symbolic constants rather than literal values.

**Can I use android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE in my xml file** rather than "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"?

This is somewhat of a good practices question rather than a get-me-unstuck one.

Comment: I think if you put android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE in your xml file your appwidget will not receive notifications. intent-filter requires a string for the action and you cannot refer to the constant that is defined in the code.

Comment: Yes, I think the answer is that the "best practice" of not using string literals directly is not supported in the XML files used in Android development. String literals are directly used and that isless than ideal and subject the usual criticism about using string literals directly in any program.

Comment: Maybe this is the best practice. As I found in the source of Android intents actions are defined as static final String. They are not defined in configuration and xml files. Maybe this is because it is a big penalty to read every time information from files. However, in your projects you can define them in XML file. But to my point of view it is better to define them as final static strings in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, Android does not allow it, and I cannot think of a compelling reason why. The question asks specifically about a standard Android string literal, rather than a custom string literal, hence I am not accepting the other answer (which is still a good answer so upvoting).

Answer (score 1):

Please use your custom intent filter action value within res/value/String.xml file and use it in all place where required i.e., manifest.xml as well as other java files.

I think this is the best way i found. Because you have to use changes at only one place and it reflects in every referred places.

Thank you,